# Best method for storing this pointer for use in WndProc

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, oop, wndproc

I'm interested to know the best / common way of storing a `this` pointer for use in the `WndProc`. I know of several approaches, but each as I understand it have their own drawbacks. My questions are:

What different ways are there of producing this kind of code:

```
CWindow::WndProc(UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM)
{
  this->DoSomething();
}
```

I can think of Thunks, HashMaps, Thread Local Storage and the Window User Data struct.

What are the pros / cons of each of these approaches?

Points awarded for code examples and recommendations.

This is purely for curiosities sake. After using MFC I've just been wondering how that works and then got to thinking about ATL etc.

**Edit:** What is the earliest place I can validly use the `HWND` in the window proc? It is documented as `WM_NCCREATE` - but if you actually experiment, that's *not* the first message to be sent to a window.

**Edit:** ATL uses a thunk for accessing the this pointer. MFC uses a hashtable lookup of `HWND`s.

Answer (score 23):

This question has many duplicates and almost-duplicates on SO, yet almost none of the answers I've seen explore the pitfalls of their chosen solutions.

There are several ways how to associate an arbitrary data pointer with a window, and there are 2 different situations to consider. Depending on the situation, the possibilities are different.

Situation 1 is when you are authoring the window class. This means you are implementing the `WNDPROC`, and it is your intention that other people use your window class in their applications. You generally do not know who will use your window class, and for what.

Situation 2 is when you are using a window class that already exists in your own application. In general, you do not have access to the window class source code, and you cannot modify it.

I'm assuming that the problem *isn't* getting the data pointer into the `WNDPROC` initially (that would just be the through the `CREATESTRUCT` with the `lpParam` parameter in `CreateWindow[ExW]`), but rather, how to store it for subsequent calls.

### Method 1: cbWndExtra

When Windows creates an instance of a window, it internally allocates a `WND` struct. This struct has a certain size, contains all sorts of window-related things, like its position, its window class, and its current WNDPROC. At the end of this struct, Windows optionally allocates a number of additional bytes that belong to the struct. The number is specified in `WNDCLASSEX.cbWndExtra`, which is used in `RegisterWindowClassEx`.

This implies that this method can only be used if you are the person who registers the window class, i.e. you are *authoring the window class*.

Applications cannot directly access the `WND` struct. Instead, use `GetWindowLong[Ptr]`. Non-negative indices access memory inside the extra bytes at the end of the struct. "0" will access the first extra bytes.

This is a clean, and fast way of doing it, if you are authoring the window class. Most Windows internal controls seem to use this method.

Unfortunately, this method does not play so well with dialogs (`DialogBox` family). You would have a dialog window class in addition to providing the dialog template, which can become cumbersome to maintain (unless you need to do so for other reasons anyway). If you do want to use it with dialogs, you must specify the window class name in the dialog template, make sure this window class is registered before showing the dialog, and you need to implement a `WNDPROC` for the dialog (or use `DefDlgProc`). Furthermore, all dialogs already reserve a certain amount of bytes in `cbWndExtra` for the dialog manager to function properly. The number of extra bytes needed is the `DLGWINDOWEXTRA` constant. This means *your* stuff needs to come *after* the extra bytes which are already reserved by the dialog. Offset all accesses to the extra memory by `DLGWINDOWEXTRA` (including the value of `cbWndExtra` which you specify in your window class).

See also below for an extra method exclusive to dialogs.

### Method 2: GWLP_USERDATA

The aforementioned `WND` struct happens to contain one pointer-sized field, which is not used by the system. It is accessed using `GetWindowLongPtr` with a negative index (namely, `GWLP_USERDATA`). A negative index will access fields inside the `WND` structure. Note that according to [this](https://winterdom.com/dev/ui/wnd/), the negative indices do not seem to represent memory offsets, but are arbitrary.

The problem with `GWLP_USERDATA` is that it is not clear, and it has not been clear in the past, what *exactly* the purpose of this field is, and hence, who the owner of this field is. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521809/who-is-owner-of-gwlp-userdata-cell). *The general consensus is that there is no consensus.* It is likely that `GWLP_USERDATA` was meant to be used by *users of the window*, and not *authors of the window class*. This implies that using it inside of the WNDPROC is strictly incorrect, as the WNDPROC is always provided by the window class author.

I am personally convinced that this is the intention of the engineers that came up with `GWLP_USERDATA` simply because if it is true, then the API as a whole is sound, extensible, and future-proof. But if it is not true, then the API is neither of those, and it would be redundant with `cbWndExtra`.

All standard windows controls that I am aware of (e.g. `BUTTON`, `EDIT`, etc.) adhere to this and do not use `GWLP_USERDATA` internally, leaving it free for the window which *uses* these controls. The problem is that there are WAY too many examples, including on MSDN and on SO, which break this rule and use `GWLP_USERDATA` for implementation of the window class. This effectively takes away the cleanest and simplest method for a control *user* to associate a context pointer with it, simply because way too many people are doing it "wrong" (according to my definition of "wrong"). At worst, the user code does not know that `GWLP_USERDATA` is occupied, and may overwrite it, which would likely crash the application.

Because of this longstanding dispute about the ownership of `GWLP_USERDATA`, it is not generally safe to use it. If you are *authoring* a window class, you probably never should have used it anyway. If you are *using* a window, you should only do so if you are certain that it is not used by the window class.

### Method 3: SetProp

The `SetProp` family of functions implements access to a property table. Each window has its own, independent properties. The key of this table is a string at API surface level, but internally it is really an ATOM.

`SetProp` can be used by window class *authors*, and window *users*, and it has issues too, but they are different from `GWLP_USERDATA`. You must make sure that the strings used as the property keys do not collide. The window user may not necessarily know what strings the window class author is using internally. Even though conflicts are unlikely, you can avoid them entirely by using a GUID as string, for example. As is evident when looking at the contents of the global ATOM table, many programs use GUIDs this way.

`SetProp` must be used with care. Most resources do not explain the pitfalls of this function. Internally, it uses `GlobalAddAtom`. This has several implications, which need to be considered when using this function:

- When calling `SetProp` (or any other API that uses the global ATOM table), instead of a string, you can use an `ATOM`, which you get when you register a new string `GlobalAddAtom`. An ATOM is just an integer which refers to one entry in the ATOM table. This will improve performance; `SetProp` internally always uses `ATOM`s as property keys, never strings. Passing a string causes `SetProp` and similar functions to internally search the ATOM table for a match first. Passing an `ATOM` directly skips searching the string in the global atom table.
- The number of possible string atoms in the global atom table is limited to 16384, system-wide. This is because atoms are 16-bit uints ranging from `0xC000` to `0xFFFF` (all values below `0xC000` are pseudo-atoms pointing to fixed strings (which are perfectly fine to use, but you cannot guarantee that nobody else is using them)). It is a bad idea to use many different property names, let alone if those names are dynamically generated at runtime. Instead, you can use a single property to store a pointer to a structure that contains all the data you need.
- If you are using a GUID, it is safe to use the same GUID for *every* window you are working with, even across different software projects, since every window has its own properties. This way, all of your software will only use up at most *two* entries in the global atom table (you'll need at most one GUID as a window class author, and at most one GUID as a window class user). In fact, it might make sense to define two de-facto standard GUIDs everyone can use for their context pointers (realistically not going to happen).
- Because properties use `GlobalAddAtom`, you must make sure that the atoms are unregistered. Global atoms are not cleaned up when the process exists and will clog up the global atom table until the operating system is restarted. To do this, you must make sure that `RemoveProp` is called. A good place for this is usually `WM_NCDESTROY`.
- Global atoms are reference-counted. This implies that the counter can overflow at some point. To protect against overflows, once the reference count of an atom reaches 65536, the atom will stay in the atom table forever, and no amount of `GlobalDeleteAtom` can get rid of it. The operating system must be restarted to free the atom table in this case.

Avoid having many different atom names if you want to use `SetProp`. Other than that, `SetProp`/`GetProp` is a very clean and defensive approach. The dangers of atom leaks could be greatly mitigated if developers agreed upon using the same 2 atom names for all windows, but that is not going to happen.

### Method 4: SetWindowSubclass

`SetWindowSubclass` is meant to allow overriding the `WNDPROC` of a specific window, so that you can handle some messages in your own callback, and delegate the rest of the messages to the original `WNDPROC`. For example, this can be used to listen for specific key combinations in an `EDIT` control, while leaving the rest of the messages to its original implementation.

A convenient side effect of `SetWindowSubclass` is that the *new*, replacement `WNDPROC` is not actually a `WNDPROC`, but a `SUBCLASSPROC`.

`SUBCLASSPROC` has 2 additional parameters, one of them is `DWORD_PTR dwRefData`. This is arbitrary pointer-sized data. The data comes from you, through the last parameter to `SetWindowSubclass`. The data is then passed to *every invocation* of the replacement `SUBCLASSPROC`. If only *every* `WNDPROC` had this parameter, then we wouldn't be in this horrible situation!

This method only helps the window class author.<sup>(1)</sup> During the initial creation of the window (e.g. `WM_CREATE`), the window subclasses itself (it can allocate memory for the `dwRefData` right there if that's appropriate). Deallocation probably best in `WM_NCDESTROY`. The rest of the code that would normally go in `WNDPROC` is moved to the replacement `SUBCLASSPROC` instead.

It can even be used in a dialog's own `WM_INITDIALOG` message. If the dialog is shown with `DialogParamW`, the last parameter can be used as `dwRefData` in a `SetWindowSubclass` call in the `WM_INITDIALOG` message. Then, all the rest of the dialog logic goes in the new `SUBCLASSPROC`, which will receive this `dwRefData` for every message. Note that this changes semantics slightly. You are now writing at the level of the dialog's *window* procedure, not the dialog procedure.

Internally, `SetWindowSubclass` uses a property (using `SetProp`) whose atom name is `UxSubclassInfo`. Every instance of `SetWindowSubclass` uses this name, so it will already be in the global atom table on practically any system. It replaces the window's original `WNDPROC` with a `WNDPROC` called `MasterSubclassProc`. That function uses the data in the `UxSubclassInfo` property to get the `dwRefData` and call all registered `SUBCLASSPROC` functions. This also implies that you should probably not use `UxSubclassInfo` as your own property name for anything.

### Method 5: Thunk

A thunk is a small function whose machine code is dynamically generated at run-time in memory. Its purpose is to call another function, but with additional parameters that seem to magically come out of nowhere.

This would let you define a function which is like `WNDPROC`, but it has one additional parameter. This parameter could be the equivalent of a "this" pointer. Then, when creating the window, you replace the original stub `WNDPROC` with a thunk that calls the real, pseudo-`WNDPROC` with an additional parameter.

The way this works is that when the thunk is created, it generates machine code in memory for a load instruction, loading the value of the extra parameter as a *constant*, and then a jump instruction to the address of the function which would normally require an additional parameter. The thunk itself can then be called as if it were a regular `WNDPROC`.

This method can be used by window class authors and is extremely fast. However, the implementation is not trivial. The [`AtlThunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/atlthunk/nf-atlthunk-atlthunk_initdata) family of functions implements this, but with a quirk. It does not add an *extra* parameter. Instead, it *replaces* the `HWND` parameter of `WNDPROC` with your arbitrary piece of data (pointer-sized). However, that is not a big problem since your arbitrary data may be a pointer to a struct containing the `HWND` of the window.

Similarly to the `SetWindowSubclass` method, you would create the thunk during window creation, using an arbitrary data pointer. Then, replace the window's `WNDPROC` with the thunk. All the real work goes in the new, pseudo-`WNDPROC` which is targeted by the thunk.

Thunks do not mess with the global atom table at all, and there are no string uniqueness considerations either. However, like everything else that is allocated in heap memory, they must be freed, and after that, the thunk may no longer be called. Since `WM_NCDESTROY` is the last message a window receives, this is the place to do that. Otherwise, you must make sure to reinstall the original `WNDPROC` when freeing the thunk.

Note that this method of smuggling a "this" pointer into a callback function is practically ubiquitous in many ecosystems, including C# interop with native C functions.

### Method 6: Global lookup table

No long explanation needed. In your application, implement a global table where you store `HWND`s as keys and context data as values. You are responsible for cleaning up the table, and, if needed, to make it sufficiently fast.

Window class authors can use private tables for their implementations, and window users can use their own tables to store application-specific information. There are no concerns about atoms or string uniqueness.

### Bottom line

These methods work if you are the *Window Class Author*:

cbWndExtra, (GWLP_USERDATA), SetProp, SetWindowSubclass, Thunk, Global lookup table.

Window Class Author means that you are writing the `WNDPROC` function. For example, you may be implementing a custom picture box control, which allows the user to pan and zoom. You may need additional data to store pan/zoom data (e.g. as a 2D transformation matrix), so that you can implement your `WM_PAINT` code correctly.

Recommendation: Avoid GWLP_USERDATA because the user code may rely on it; use cbWndExtra if possible.

These methods work if you are the *Window User*:

GWLP_USERDATA, SetProp, Global lookup table.

Window User means you are creating one or more of the windows and use them in your own application. For example, you may be creating a variable number of buttons dynamically, and each of them is associated with a different piece of data that is relevant when it is being clicked.

Recommendation: Use GWLP_USERDATA if it's a standard Windows control, or you are sure that the control doesn't use it internally. Otherwise, `SetProp`.

### Extra mention when using dialogs

Dialogs, by default, use a window class that has `cbWndExtra` set to `DLGWINDOWEXTRA`. It is possible to define your own window class for a dialog, where you allocate, say, `DLGWINDOWEXTRA + sizeof(void*)`, and then access `GetWindowLongPtrW(hDlg, DLGWINDOWEXTRA)`. But while doing so you will find yourself having to answer questions you won't like. For example, which `WNDPROC` do you use (answer: you can use `DefDlgProc`), or which class styles do you use (the default dialogs happen to use `CS_SAVEBITS | CS_DBLCLKS`, but good luck finding an authoritative reference).

Within the `DLGWINDOEXTRA` bytes, dialogs happen to reserve a pointer-sized field, which can be accessed using `GetWindowLongPtr` with index `DWLP_USER`. This is kind of an additional `GWLP_USERDATA`, and, in theory, has the same problems. In practice I have only ever seen this used inside the `DLGPROC` which ends up being passed to `DialogBox[Param]`. After all, the *window user* still has `GWLP_USERDATA`. So it is probably safe to use for the *window class implementation* in practically every situation.

Comment: Incredibly well written answer, thank you a lot!

Comment: +9000 This answer is absolutely a Top 10 that I have read in my 13 years here.  Thank you.  Please continue to post amazing answers like this one!

Comment: The fact that you only got 21 upvotes is proof that win32 is antiquated. This answer was very impressive; and it even is demotivating me from continuing programming. When I thought that SetProp was new; you come with Thunk. Even I knew Windows allowed dynamic creation of functions. But using dynamic functions as lamdas blew me away. What also blew me away was your detailed detailed knowledge of the Win32 API. I always used GWL_USERDATA to store my object. Now I understand that extra window data is better. I never knew a window user needed to use GWL_userdata

Comment: @user13947194 Win32 may be considered antiquated as you say, but as a matter of fact, almost all higher level APIs are still based on these things. That means they need to be understood. Declining knowledge about Win32 in the programming community has been leading to ever declining software quality over the past 20 years. It also means Microsoft is doing a lot of damage by neglecting Win32. Maybe I'm a dinosaur at this point, but I firmly believe this needs to stop, and Win32 fundamentals need to be taught rigorously. Greed and rapid development practices have done too much damage already.

Comment: OK. Well thanks for your knowledge because currently I am stuck with raw Win32 anyhow. Well atleast I have my own library and framework over it.  Just want to finish my Dialog Builder and IDE so I can jump into some direct x/ direct 3d apps. Note that currently I use GDI to do all of my Painting. peace.

Comment: What happens when **RemoveProp** is not called? For instance, an app might crash or the user forcefully terminate it in taskmanager. In that case, do the props linger forever?

Answer (score 14):

In your constructor, call **CreateWindowEx** with "this" as the lpParam argument.

Then, on WM_NCCREATE, call the following code:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) ((CREATESTRUCT*)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Then, at the top of your window procedure you could do the following:

```
MyWindowClass *wndptr = (MyWindowClass*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
wndptr->DoSomething();
```

Of course, you could use the same technique to call something like your function above:

```
wndptr->WndProc(msg, wparam, lparam);
```

... which can then use its "this" pointer as expected.

Comment: Why do you need `SetWindowPos()`?

Comment: @Timmmm [from the man](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra): "Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using SetWindowLongPtr will not take effect until you call the SetWindowPos function".

Comment: This answer ignores the drawbacks of the presented approach and also the other approaches available. Voting down.

Answer (score 14):

While using the **SetWindowLongPtr** and **GetWindowLongPtr** to access the **GWL_USERDATA** might sound like a good idea, I would strongly recommend **not** using this approach.

This is the exactly the approached used by the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/ccpp.html) editor and in recent years it has caused nothing but pain.

I think what happens is third party windows messages are sent to [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/ccpp.html) that also have their **GWL_USERDATA** value set. One application in particular was a Microsoft tool that provied an alternative way to enter Asian characters in any windows application (i.e. some sort of software keyboard utility).

The problem is [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/ccpp.html) always assumes the **GWL_USERDATA** data was set by it and tries to use the data as a *this pointer*, which then results in a crash.

If I was to do it all again with, what I know now, I would go for a cached hash lookup approach where the window handle is used as the key.

Comment: This can be remedied by setting extra window data in the WNDCLASSEX struct and use that new offset in Get/SetWindowLongPtr instead of GWL_USERDATA.

Comment: Window *messages* do not have GWL_USERDATA. *Windows* have. Don't peek at messages for other windows, and expect to get the this pointer for your window. 

And note that you should own both the window and the window *class* : http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/03/384285.aspx

Comment: The problem is there are instances when Windows sends the application a message with a handle to a window that is was not created by the application. 

But this approach assumes every message sent to the application will be for a window created by the application and that is just not the case.

Comment: I got inspired by this thread and as a result I re-worked the Zeus code to use a hash lookup table to do the mapping. This new approach seems to be working very well.

Comment: @MSalters _Don't peek at messages for other windows_ How would one be able to tell the difference between the two inside one's own window's `WndProc`?

Comment: @legends2k: Well, you're not going to get messages in **your** WndProc from **random** windows. And for messages that you're not handling anyway (e.g. non-client paint), you can also ignore those checks. But the moment that you want your `WndProc` to do something for a window, you'd better check that you indeed have the right window.

Comment: But that's exactly what jussij warns about: _there are instances when Windows sends the application a message with a handle to a window that is was not created by the application ... this approach assumes every message sent to the application will be for a window created by the application and that is just not the case._

Comment: @JohannGerell Would setting the extra window data trick work if what jussij mentions is true? I.e. message sent to `WndProc` with `hwnd` to a window not being created by the application? Hence doing a `GetWindowLongPtr` nevertheless fails both with or without extra data?

Comment: @legends2k: I haven't tried and don't have time to do that now either, but if you retrieve data from the new offset and it's not null, then you cast it and use it and it'll (most likely) either work (if it's indeed your data) or crash the application (if the data isn't what you expected). I don't know what guarantees Win32 gives you about window handles from other processes. If this worries you, you can always verify that the window was created in this process using `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `GetProcessId` - they might come with an overhead though, so it's your call.

Comment: Why do you link to "Zeus" every single time you use the word?  Weird self-plug.

Comment: This sounds like he was confusing one problem for another.  If he was getting window messages from other random windows on his WndProc, all kinds of things would explode as it manipulated some other window as if it was his own.  This just happened to be the thing that exploded first, so he thought this was the problem.  There was probably a nasty bug in some other software injecting into his (like that IME).  There's nothing wrong with storing your interface pointer with GWLP_USERDATA--that's what it's for.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `GetWindowLongPtr()`/`SetWindowLongPtr()` (or the deprecated `GetWindowLong()`/`SetWindowLong()`).  They are fast and do exactly what you want to do.  The only tricky part is figuring out when to call `SetWindowLongPtr()` - You need to do this when the first window message is sent, which is `WM_NCCREATE`.
See [this article](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1810.asp) for sample code and a more in-depth discussion.

Thread-local storage is a bad idea, since you may have multiple windows running in one thread.

A hash map would also work, but computing the hash function for every window message (and there are a *LOT*) can get expensive.

I'm not sure how you mean to use thunks; how are you passing around the thunks?

Comment: As far as thunks go, you could have a separate thunk for each window (generated dynamically).  You would register this thunk as the window procedure, and this thunk would already contain the object pointer.  I *believe* this is the ATL/WTL approach.

Comment: WM_NCCREATE isn't necessarily the first message sent, but the first for which a CREATESTRUCT with `this` information can accompany the message.

Answer (score 6):

I've used SetProp/GetProp to store a pointer to data with the window itself. I'm not sure how it stacks up to the other items you mentioned.

Comment: I think Get/SetProp is definitely a clean way of doing it. It's a tad slower than Get/SetWindowLong (which is O(1)), but as long as there's not "many" properties set for the window, I doubt that this will be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GetWindowLongPtr` and `SetWindowLongPtr`; use `GWLP_USERDATA` to attach the pointer to the window. However, if you are writing a custom control I would suggest to use extra window bytes to get the job done. While registering the window class set the `WNDCLASS::cbWndExtra` to the size of the data like this, `wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(Ctrl*);`.

You can get and set the value using `GetWindowLongPtr` and `SetWindowLongPtr` with `nIndex` parameter set to `0`. This method can save `GWLP_USERDATA` for other purposes.

The disadvantage with `GetProp` and `SetProp`, there will be a string comparison to get/set a property.

Comment: This remedies the issue mentioned by Adrian Lopez by avoiding the usage of `GWL_USERDATA`.

Comment: Does not explain in detail or provide any examples demonstrating how to correctly use the window class to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to SetWindowLong() / GetWindowLong() security, according to Microsoft:

> The SetWindowLong function fails if
>   the window specified by the hWnd
>   parameter does not belong to the same
>   process as the calling thread.

Unfortunately, until the release of a [Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms04-032.mspx) on October 12, 2004, Windows [would not enforce this rule](http://osdir.com/ml/security.vulnerabilities/2004-10/msg00009.html), allowing an application to set any other application's GWL_USERDATA. Therefore, applications running on unpatched systems are vulnerable to attack through calls to SetWindowLong().

Answer (score 2):

I recommend setting a `thread_local` variable just before calling `CreateWindow`, and reading it in your `WindowProc` to find out the `this` variable (I presume you have control over `WindowProc`).

This way you'll have the `this`/`HWND` association on the very first message sent to you window.

With the other approaches suggested here chances are you'll miss on some messages: those sent before `WM_CREATE` / `WM_NCCREATE` / `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`.

```
class Window
{
    // ...
    static thread_local Window* _windowBeingCreated;
    static thread_local std::unordered_map<HWND, Window*> _hwndMap;
    // ...
    HWND _hwnd;
    // ...
    // all error checking omitted
    // ...
    void Create (HWND parentHWnd, UINT nID, HINSTANCE hinstance)
    {
        // ...
        _windowBeingCreated = this;
        ::CreateWindow (YourWndClassName, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, w, h, parentHWnd, (HMENU) nID, hinstance, NULL);
    }

    static LRESULT CALLBACK Window::WindowProcStatic (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
    {
        Window* _this;
        if (_windowBeingCreated != nullptr)
        {
            _hwndMap[hwnd] = _windowBeingCreated;
            _windowBeingCreated->_hwnd = hwnd;
            _this = _windowBeingCreated;
            windowBeingCreated = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            auto existing = _hwndMap.find (hwnd);
            _this = existing->second;
        }

        return _this->WindowProc (msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    LRESULT Window::WindowProc (UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            // ....
```

Answer (score 1):

ATL's thunk is the most efficent. the thunk executes once and replaces the callback function for the WINPROC to the classes own message processing member function. subsiquent messages are passed by a direct call to the classes member function by windows. it doesnt get any faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used the lpParam parameter of `CreateWindowEx`:

> lpParam [in, optional] Type: LPVOID
>
> Pointer to a value to be passed to the window through the CREATESTRUCT
>   structure (lpCreateParams member) pointed to by the lParam param of
>   the WM_CREATE message. This message is sent to the created window by
>   this function before it returns. If an application calls CreateWindow
>   to create a MDI client window, lpParam should point to a
>   CLIENTCREATESTRUCT structure. If an MDI client window calls
>   CreateWindow to create an MDI child window, lpParam should point to a
>   MDICREATESTRUCT structure. lpParam may be NULL if no additional data
>   is needed.

The trick here is to have a `static` `std::map` of HWND to class instance pointers. Its possible that the `std::map::find` might be more performant than the `SetWindowLongPtr` method. Its certainly easier to write test code using this method though.

Btw if you are using a win32 dialog then you'll need to use the `DialogBoxParam` function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the problem that occurred in the Zeus editor, simply specify the window in the GetMessage function:

```
BOOL GetMessage(
LPMSG lpMsg,
HWND  hWnd, /*A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved.*/
UINT  wMsgFilterMin,
UINT  wMsgFilterMax
);
```

**NOTE**
The window must belong to the current thread.

[Easy to read Documentation of the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage)