# Delete inside of class

Tags: c++, class, delete-operator

I got some weird problem. I use delete operator inside of class method and I want to know how solve this problem.

This is code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int a;

        ~A() {
            cout << "call ~A()" << endl;
        }

        void action()
        {
            /* code here */
            delete this; //this line depends on some if statements
            /* code here */
        }

        void test2() {
            cout << "call test2()" <<  a << endl;
        }

        void test() {
            a = 10;
            cout << "call test()" << endl;

            action();

            //how can I check if data is deleted?
            test2();
        }
};

int main()
{

    A* a = new A();
    a->test();

}
```

How can I check if data is deleted by delete operator?
Is it even possible?

Comment: You are deleting instance of the class within its non-static member function. I think you need to ask yourself "What am I trying to achieve?"

Comment: For example I got gui, when Button that is child of this Window calls action closeWindow() I need to delete Window, but don't know exactly how, I thought it will be fastest way or use somekind of dispatcher

Comment: You need to destroy actual window, but who said you need to delete instance of C++ class that represents this window? If you are doing Windows message processing, here is [some information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273830/win32-more-object-oriented-window-message-handling-system/8274312#8274312). I suggest you also read comments, Remy Lebeau gives interesting insights on how it is done within Borland VCL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Using `delete this;` is nearly always "bad". There are exceptions, but those are really unusual. Think about what you are trying to do. Most of the time, this means that you should have a wrapper object and an inner object that is created/deleted by the wrapper object.
2. You can't check if something has been deleted (in a reliable way/portable way). In your particular test-case, you are exercising "undefined behaviour" by "using an object after it has been destroyed", which means you can't really tell what is going to happen. You have to trust the C++ runtime that `delete` does what it says on the label.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ there are other return values available than `void`. Therefore  your `action` can return something that indicates if `this` has been deleted or not.

Note that you should not access any non-static data members or call any non-static member functions after deleteing `this`. Some people feel it to be difficult to guarantee so they ban `delete this` altogether.

Note to opponents that [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html) claims that `delete this` is legal construct and I haven't also found anything forbidding it.

Comment: Practically, avoiding accessing non-static data is enough, but strictly speaking you're probably still invoking UB. Just don't do this.

Comment: I can not find UB for that case from standard. Can you show where? I am not big fan of such self owning objects. Sometimes such may be reasonable. Then delete this is OK to avoid artificial owners and the `owner->deleteMe(this)` bloat that still ends in same situation: may access nothing nonstatic.

Comment: I understand. I thought when action() will return for example even boolean value it will be still wrong way, that's why I create this question, anyway thanks :P

Comment: @ÖöTiib: The standard does not list every case that is undefined. By contrast, cases that are not defined are... undefined. While you're in a member function, it's expected that the owning object exists. Simple as that. There is basically never anything reasonable about `delete this` -- you're messing up ownership semantics.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For example some active objects have to be self-owned because they are the root of ownership tree. Making them artificially not root adds concurrency problems for no gain.