# C++ WINAPI Dynamic Wrapper Class

Tags: c++, class, winapi

First off, I want to say, for anyone who is going to say "why am I reinventing the wheel", I am doing this for fun, and for a project of mine I'm currently working on.

As you can see from the code below, I am trying to dynamically create a window and a button, but something I'm having trouble with is adding a function to that button when it's clicked.

I know it would be really simple to go into the window procedure in `WM_COMMAND` and do so there, but that's missing the whole point of what I'm trying to accomplish here, have it so I can simple call `btn.add(params)` to a certain window, and add a certain function to that button by calling say `btn.click(function);` without having to go into the window procedure itself when adding the controls.

How would I accomplish this?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

WNDCLASSEX defWndClass = { 0 };

class WinForm
{
private:
    HWND WindowHandle;
    std::thread Thread;
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>> ControlHandles;

public:
    ~WinForm();
    WinForm(std::string ClassName, std::string WindowName, bool Threaded = false, int Width = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int Height = CW_USEDEFAULT, WNDPROC WindowProcedure = nullptr, WNDCLASSEX WndClass = defWndClass);
    bool AddButton(std::string ButtonName, POINT Location, int Width, int Height);
};

WinForm::~WinForm()
{
    if (Thread.joinable())
    {
        Thread.join();
    }
}

WinForm::WinForm(std::string ClassName, std::string WindowName, bool Threaded, int Width, int Height, WNDPROC WindowProcedure, WNDCLASSEX WndClass)
    :WindowHandle(nullptr)
{
    if (WindowProcedure == nullptr)
    {
        WindowProcedure = [](HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)->LRESULT __stdcall
        {
            switch (msg)
            {
                /*
                case WM_PAINT:
                    break;
                    */

            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;

            case WM_CREATE:
                break;

            default:
                return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
            }
            return 0;
        };
    }

    if (WndClass.cbSize == 0)
    {
        WndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        WndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
        WndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
        WndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        WndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        WndClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
        WndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
        WndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        WndClass.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        WndClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
        WndClass.lpszClassName = ClassName.c_str();
        WndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    }

    if (RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
    {
        if (Threaded)
        {
            // can't do that!
        }
        else
        {
            WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), WindowName.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
            if (WindowHandle)
            {
                ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

                // don't put message loop here!
            }
        }
    }
}

bool WinForm::AddButton(std::string ButtonName, POINT Location, int Width, int Height)
{
    for (std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>>::iterator it = ControlHandles.begin(); it != ControlHandles.end(); ++it)
    {
        auto& tu = *it;
        auto& str = std::get<0>(tu);
        if (ButtonName.compare(str) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::size_t ID = 1;
    for (std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>>::iterator it = ControlHandles.begin(); it != ControlHandles.end(); ++it, ++ID)
    {
        if (std::get<1>(*it) != ID)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    HWND ButtonHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        0, "button", ButtonName.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, Location.x, Location.y, Width, Height,
        WindowHandle, (HMENU)ID, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(WindowHandle, GWL_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
    ShowWindow(ButtonHandle, SW_SHOW);
    ControlHandles.push_back(std::make_tuple(ButtonName, ID, ButtonHandle));

    //SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CREATE, 0, 0);
    return true;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    WinForm Form("Class", "Title", false);
    POINT pt = { 50, 50 };
    Form.AddButton("NewButton", pt, 80, 50);

    MSG msg = { nullptr };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}
```

Comment: One way to do this is to have the window procedure consult a map from buttons to functions. When you add a button, add an entry to the map.

Comment: No matter what you do, the parent window of the button is going to receive a [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bn-clicked) notification via `WM_COMMAND` when the button is clicked. If the parent window doesn't handle the message, it ends up going to `DefWindowProc()` and gets ignored. So, the parent window needs to handle `WM_COMMAND`. When the notification code is `BN_CLICKED`, the parent can look up the provided `HWND` in its list of buttons, and if found then call the corresponding function if one has been assigned.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Hate to be the one, but I'll be the one to throw cold water on this project.  To create a C++ wrapper for the Windows API, you better know the Windows API itself from its `C`-based roots.  That means having concrete `C`-based examples that work, plus having books is the way to learn the API.  Otherwise you totally miss the things mentioned by @RemyLebeau.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,c038d2f6b223a3ca,references

Comment: Not a problem to reinvent the wheel but why is this ugly mix of C and C++? Maybe you cannot replace 3-4 "C++" lines with pure C? For that reason I will not try to find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The parent window of the button is going to receive a [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bn-clicked) notification via `WM_COMMAND` when the button is clicked.  If the parent window doesn't handle the message, it ends up going to `DefWindowProc()` and gets ignored.  So, the parent window needs to handle `WM_COMMAND`.  When the notification code is `BN_CLICKED`, simply lookup the provided button `HWND` in your list of buttons, and if found then call the corresponding function, if one has been assigned.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class WinForm
{
public:
    using ControlActionFunc = std::function<void(const std::string &)>;

    WinForm(std::string ClassName, std::string WindowName, bool Threaded = false, int Width = CW_USEDEFAULT, int Height = CW_USEDEFAULT);

    ~WinForm();

    bool AddButton(const std::string &ButtonName, POINT Location, int Width, int Height, ControlActionFunc OnClick);

private:
    HWND WindowHandle;
    std::thread Thread;

    using ControlInfo = std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND, ControlActionFunc>;
    using ControlInfoVector = std::vector<ControlInfo>;
    ControlInfoVector Controls;

    static LRESULT __stdcall StaticWindowProcedure(HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

protected:
    virtual LRESULT WindowProcedure(UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
};

class MainAppWinForm : public WInForm
{
public:
    using WinForm::WinForm;

protected:
    LRESULT WindowProcedure(UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) override;
};

WinForm::WinForm(std::string ClassName, std::string WindowName, bool Threaded, int Width, int Height)
    : WindowHandle(nullptr)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    WNDCLASSEX WndClass = {};

    bool isRegistered = GetClassInfoEx(hInstance, ClassName.c_str(), &WndClass);
    if ((!isRegistered) || (WndClass.lpfnWndProc != &WinForm::StaticWindowProcedure))
    {
        if (isRegistered)
            UnregisterClass(ClassName.c_str(), hInstance);

        WndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        WndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
        WndClass.lpfnWndProc = &WinForm::StaticWindowProcedure;
        WndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        WndClass.cbWndExtra = sizeof(WinForm*);
        WndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
        WndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
        WndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        WndClass.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        WndClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
        WndClass.lpszClassName = ClassName.c_str();
        WndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);

        if (!RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
            return;
    }

    if (Threaded)
    {
        // can't do that!
        return;
    }

    WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), WindowName.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, this);
    if (!WindowHandle)
        return;

    ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

    // don't put message loop here!
}

WinForm::~WinForm()
{
    if (Thread.joinable())
    {
        Thread.join();
    }
}

LRESULT __stdcall WinForm::StaticWindowProcedure(HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    WinForm *This;
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        This = static_cast<WinForm*>(reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lp)->lpCreateParams);
        This->WindowHandle = window;
        SetWindowLongPtr(window, 0, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(This));
    }
    else
        This = reinterpret_cast<WinForm*>(GetWindowLongPtr(window, 0));

    if (This)
        return This->WindowProcedure(msg, wp, lp);

    return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
}

LRESULT WinForm::WindowProcedure(UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        /*
        case WM_PAINT:
            break;
        */

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (lp != 0)
            {
                if (HIWORD(wp) == BN_CLICKED)
                {
                    HWND ControlWindow = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lp);

                    auto it = std::find_if(Controls.begin(), Controls.end(),
                        [](ControlInfo &info){ return (std::get<2>(info) == ControlWindow); }
                    );

                    if (it != Controls.end())
                    {
                        auto &tu = *it;
                        auto actionFunc = std::get<3>(tu);
                        if (actionFunc) actionFunc(std::get<0>(tu));
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_CREATE:
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, msg, wp, lp);
}

bool WinForm::AddButton(const std::string &ButtonName, POINT Location, int Width, int Height, ControlActionFunc OnClick)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(Controls.begin(), Controls.end(),
        [&](ControlInfo &info){ return (std::get<0>(info).compare(ButtonName) == 0); }
    );

    if (it != Controls.end()) {
        return false;
    }

    std::size_t ID = 1;
    auto matchesID = [&](ControlInfo &info){ return (std::get<1>(tu) == ID); };
    while (std::find_if(Controls.begin(), Controls.end(), matchesID) != Controls.end()) {
        ++ID;
    }

    HWND ButtonHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        0, "button", ButtonName.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, Location.x, Location.y, Width, Height,
        WindowHandle, (HMENU)ID, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(WindowHandle, GWL_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
    if (!ButtonHandle)
        return false;

    Controls.push_back(std::make_tuple(ButtonName, ID, ButtonHandle, std::move(OnClick)));
    return true;
}

LRESULT MainAppWinForm::WindowProcedure(UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    if (msg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return WinForm::WindowProcedure(msg, wp, lp);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    MainAppWinForm Form("Class", "Title", false);

    POINT pt = { 50, 50 };
    Form.AddButton("NewButton", pt, 80, 50,
        [](const std::string &ButtonName){ MessageBox(NULL, ButtonName.c_str(), "button clicked", MB_OK); }
    );

    MSG msg = { nullptr };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also see

[Class method for WndProc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727015/)

[Win32: More "object oriented" window message handling system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273830/)

[Best method for storing this pointer for use in WndProc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117792/)

Comment: I couldn't compile your code on VS2017. I made some changes but there is a main issue, in that when `This->WindowProcedure(msg, wp, lp);` is called at first, there is no `WindowHandle`, subsequently `CreateWindowEx` fails

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I wrote the code from memory, I didn't try to compile it. Wouldn't surprise me if it needs further tweaking. But it should be clear what the intent of the code is trying to demonstate. I fixed the `WindowHandle` issue, though.

Comment: for top-level windows first message is `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` (before `WM_NCCREATE`), as result will be ignored. if want handle it, and any possible messages before `WM_NCCREATE`, too save pointer to `WinForm` in tls, in `StaticWindowProcedure` - get it from tls, assign to window via `SetWindowLongPtr` and change `GWLP_WNDPROC` to say `StaticWindowProcedure2`. inside this we already unconditionally got pointer to `WinForm` via `GetWindowLongPtr` - never will be 0.

Comment: I see in order for this to work you would have to use WndClass.cbWndExtra = sizeof(WinForm*) or it will not work. Now that's an issue because when you close one window with this method every window you have will also close.

Comment: @Joshua you don't have to use `cbWndExtra`, `GWLP_USERDATA` will work, too. All HWNDs have `GWLP_USERDATA` available for free, which makes it appealing for users to use. In this case, I chose to use `cbWndExtra` to keep the `WinForm*` pointer private and leave `GWLP_USERDATA` free for the caller to use for its own purposes. And no, closing one window does not affect other windows. Every individual `WinForm` HWND allocated in this code has its own distinct `WinForm*` pointer assigned to it. There is no linkage between multiple `WinForm` instances

Comment: When I create another instance of the window and close it, with the proper destruction in WM_DESTROY being PostQuitMessage(0); Every instance of the window destroys along with the one I distinctly closed. Run the code yourself and you will see if you create another window and close one of those two, they will both close.

Comment: @Joshua if you run multiple `WinForm` instances, then you should not be calling `PostQuitMessage()` in response to `WM_DESTROY` unconditionally. That posts a `WM_QUIT` message that ends the message loop in `main()`. Don't call `PostQuitMessage()` until you are ready to exit your app, such as when your "main window" is closed. See [Closing the window](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/closing-the-window): "*In your **main application window**, you will typically respond to WM_DESTROY by calling PostQuitMessage.*" I tweaked my example to distinguish this responsibility.