# How to wrap a win32 WndProc into a C++ class?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, wrapper, wndproc

Is this even possible? For example, let's say I have the following:

```
class Window {
private:
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
public:
    inline WNDCLASSEX getWindowClass() {
        return wc;
    }
    Window();
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam, WPARAM wParam);
}

void RegisterWindow(Window win) {
    WNDCLASSEX* wc = win.getWindowClass();
    RegisterClassEx(wc);

}
```

Now, somewhere there is going to be a section (probably in the constructor of the `Window` class, where it's necessary to assign the `WNDCLASSEX` a `WndProc`, which is noted in the `Window` class. The only issue is that, because it's a part of a class, there an error will be raised. Thus, how is this achieved? Is it made static? Even so, if the class wraps it it is still part of the class in some way. If I create it outside of the class, that simply obliterates the point.

Comment: See MFC, it's WndProc's wrapped into C++ classes

Comment: Don't ever see MFC. For anything.g

Comment: Don't have anything above Express edition, therefore I cannot use it.

Comment: [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) also shows how, and is much more modern style than MFC.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117792/best-method-for-storing-this-pointer-for-use-in-wndproc?rq=1 which has a great discussion: http://web.archive.org/web/20051125022758/www.rpi.edu/~pudeyo/articles/wndproc/

Comment: Also, an easier article, but not as in-depth: http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/WindowClass.html (particularly helpful paragraph starts "the reason for this problem is...")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the `this` pointer as `GWLP_USERDATA` to `SetWindowLongPtr`, which effectively allows you to simply forward the free function to the member function.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite following: what do you mean by GWLP_USERDATA and SetWindowLongPtr?

Comment: Well, I can't quite use that because my `HWND` hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: @Holland I'm not sure what you mean by that. After you call `CreateWindow`, call `SetWindowLongPtr`. If you want to connect everything up sooner, use the `lpParam`  parameter.

Comment: Understood, I got it going now. Thanks.

Comment: [`SetProp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632594.aspx) is preferable to `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_USERDATA)`, since you aren't fighting for a scarce resource (the window extra bytes).

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-application-state-) of official Microsoft documentation shown such class:

```cpp
template <class DERIVED_TYPE> 
class BaseWindow
{
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        DERIVED_TYPE *pThis = NULL;

        if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
        {
            CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
            pThis = (DERIVED_TYPE*)pCreate->lpCreateParams;
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pThis);

            pThis->m_hwnd = hwnd;
        }
        else
        {
            pThis = (DERIVED_TYPE*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        }
        if (pThis)
        {
            return pThis->HandleMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        else
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    BaseWindow() : m_hwnd(NULL) { }

    BOOL Create(
        PCWSTR lpWindowName,
        DWORD dwStyle,
        DWORD dwExStyle = 0,
        int x = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int y = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int nWidth = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int nHeight = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND hWndParent = 0,
        HMENU hMenu = 0
        )
    {
        WNDCLASS wc = {0};

        wc.lpfnWndProc   = DERIVED_TYPE::WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance     = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();

        RegisterClass(&wc);

        m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            dwExStyle, ClassName(), lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,
            nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this
            );

        return (m_hwnd ? TRUE : FALSE);
    }

    HWND Window() const { return m_hwnd; }

protected:

    virtual PCWSTR  ClassName() const = 0;
    virtual LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;

    HWND m_hwnd;
};

class MainWindow : public BaseWindow<MainWindow>
{
public:
    PCWSTR  ClassName() const { return L"Sample Window Class"; }
    LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

LRESULT MainWindow::HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));
            EndPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MainWindow win;

    if (!win.Create(L"Learn to Program Windows", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(win.Window(), nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```